# Characterisation of continuous functions whose support is compact

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I saw this question some time ago but I can't remember where. Basically the question ask to find the set of all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose support $\text{supp}(f) := \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{K}: f(x) \ne 0 \}}$ is compact where $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$.

The question did not specify a topology so I'm assuming the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and on $\mathbb{C}$. and subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q}$. My idea is to look at closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, and work with its preimage in $\mathbb{K}$. However I do not have any idea how to proceed. Please help?

Comment: Normally, the support is rather defined as $\overline{\{\,x\in \mathbb K:f(x)\ne0\,\}}$. With your definiiton, the problem becomes literally trivial

Comment: Oops, you're right. I forgot the closure, thanks.

Comment: Then again, what kind of classification would be suitable? You might exhibit specific such functions, say with $f_n(x)=0$ for $|x|\ge n$ (and $f_n(x)\ne0$ othrwise). Then any continuous function with compact support is of the form $f(x)=f_n(x)g(x)$ with continous $g$ for some $n$ ...

Comment: The question ask to find all of them, so I guess there's a general characterisation? Or is it impossible to find it?